# Bulk database insert into multiple tables(with mutual associations) in PHP

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a large amount of data I am trying to insert into database(the order I'm working with is `1e+5`-`1e+6`). I am using doctrine and my first approach follows the guidelines here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html

However I am running out of memory(the dreaded `Allowed memory size of ## bytes exhausted.`). There seems to be a memory leak or something within doctrine.

The function that causes this is rather simple:

```
private function insertCompareBatch($comparedProducts)
{
    foreach ($comparedProducts as $comparedProduct) {
        $this->entityManager->persist($comparedProduct->getProduct());
        $this->entityManager->persist($comparedProduct);
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $this->entityManager->clear();
}
```

My first question is:
**Is there a way to make the doctrine approach work?**

### Things I've tried:

(I.e. **DO NOT** suggest the following)

- **Increasing the memory limit.** (I'm already at the max I can go.)
- **Disabling the SQL logger** (Helped a little, but not enough.)
- **Unsetting/nulling things** (I already overwrite the parameter in the parent function, freeing to be gc'd. Which it then is.)
- **Messing with GC directly** (It's pointless, if there is anything to GC, the engine will do so when it runs out of memory.)

### Alternative approaches:

When this didn't work, I tried looking for other solutions. And discovered `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

However I am not sure how to implement that. Doctrine helpfully handles the auto-increment columns and associations.

I can easily write a bunch of `.csv`s for both the entities persisted above, but how do I create the association between them?

The `ComparedProduct` entity has a join column to the `Product` entity(e.g. `product_id`). I do not know the `product_id` yet, because it hasn't been inserted.

**If using doctrine is out of the question, how do I make this approach work?**